# Breaking out a few QFP footprint to a small connector

Tags: connector, soldering, breakout

I have a PCB that has an realtek RTS5169 controller IC(QFP-48) on it. The IC itself is attached to USB data lines. I want to remove this controller and add another USB device to the PCB. Now I don't really know what is the best way to attach a flat connector to this footprint. Essentially I only need 4 wires of the entire footprint but since the PCB will be in a mobile device I'm not sure how to proceed. Is there some best practice kind of way to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What footprint? Also "USB" can mean anything, there's some 50+ different kinds of connectors. You need to post a photo.

Comment: @Lundin It's a QFP footprint like mentioned in the title. There is no connector. I want to attach some kind of a connector. It doesn't really matter which one. It's USB 2.0. With D+ and D- data lines which feed directly into the IC.

Comment: "QFP footprint" doesn't mean anything. There are pitches from 0.5 up to 1.27mm and depending on pad size it may or may not be feasible to solder a wire directly to the pad. Otherwise you need to hunt down a better spot by scraping off the solder mask somewhere etc.